# Permission Denied IOError

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a Django application which saves a file in `/opt/Webapp/userfiles/`but Apache will not permit this.

In my settings file I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'userfiles')
```

but I have also tried with

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/opt/Webapp/userfiles'
```

The full error is:

```
IOError at /jobs/new
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/opt/Webapp/userfiles/770976f582c9a40152505b9e456bfd2d547ec9e7353c766f1c0e0e9a.py'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://10.5.1.133/jobs/new
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/opt/Webapp/userfiles/770976f582c9a40152505b9e456bfd2d547ec9e7353c766f1c0e0e9a.py'
Exception Location: /opt/Webapp/jobs/views.py in upload, line 188
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/opt/Webapp',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_admin_tools-0.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python27.zip',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change permissions of directory with chmod and shown commands. Or change your directory. I don't think that /opt is the best place for such files.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions - Understanding and Using File Permissions

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering that. I tried to save to /test but that didn't work either...